# All changes are commited and pushed but xcode shows ? signs?

Tags: ios, xcode, git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using git and latest version of source tree for version control. And it seems to be working fine, for the most time. But sometimes xcode shows ? signs for some files like they are unversioned, although they are. I even pushed them to server and some of my colleagues pulled them so they are in the repo.

Is there a way for xcode to "see" them, some reset, or something? Because I like to use nice features like blame and history from xode, and now it seems i can't.

Comment: In  `Xcode > Preferences > Source Control` you've got some refresh settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should try right click on the file with ? sign and choose `Show in Finder`, after you get the path to the file, you can run a `git status` on the folder to see if the file is really committed and pushed.

I've met such problem when using `git submodules` and I choose to `copy files if necessary` when I was adding the files to my project, which leads to creating some copies that are not staged in the version control system.